# Error to send a file to AWS S3 from Java/Spring

Tags: java, spring, amazon-s3

I'm trying to send a file to AWS S3 from my Java/Spring application, but I'm getting this error. I check around for this param and I didn't find anything in the docs. Does someone know how to fix it?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Java method

```
    public void uploadS3(File file) throws IOException {

    AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(applicationProperties.getAwsAccessKey(),applicationProperties.getAwsAccessSecret());
    AmazonS3 s3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder
        .standard()
        .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
        .withRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_1)
        .build();

    String fileNameHash = buildNameHash(file.getOriginalFilename(), System.currentTimeMillis());
    String filename = fileNameHash+"."+ FilenameUtils.getExtension(file.getOriginalFilename());

    try {
        s3.putObject(applicationProperties.getAwsImageBucket(), filename, file);
    } catch (AmazonServiceException e) {
        log.error("[uploadS3] error: {}", e.getErrorMessage());
    }
}
```

Error:

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: SIGNING_NAME
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1055)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)

Comment: Are you sue that all AWS related dependencies you use have the same version? Could you post full stack trace?

Comment: use sdk version 1.11.757

Comment: @MaciejWalkowiak You're right the version of the related dependencies was not right, I just changed and now everything is right, Thanks.

Comment: @Tanino I added full answer that also shows how avoid these kind of issues in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In cases like this, when the exception relates to missing field or missing class it most likely means that there are multiple versions of AWS SDK on the classpath. Always make sure that different dependencies from AWS SDK have the version aligned.

To make the process simpler, instead of listing all dependencies with versions like this:

```xml
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-ec2</artifactId>
      <version>1.10.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
      <version>1.10.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-dynamodb</artifactId>
      <version>1.10.10</version>
    </dependency>
  <dependencies>
```

You can use a BOM (Bill of Materials) in the `dependencyManagement` section:

```xml
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-bom</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.10</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-ec2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-dynamodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use another way to upload your files to S3 like showed bellow on the image

[image]

> A pre-signed URL allows you to grant temporary access to users who
> don’t have permission to directly run AWS operations in your account.
> A pre-signed URL is signed with your credentials and can be used by
> any user

this [link](https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-properly-use-aws-s3-presigned-urls-147a449227f9) explain how to use this technical